# continue key for multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a little problem and I need some help with it. I am trying to show the number of purchase item in an invoice. So I have a multiple page, but each page is limited to a list of only 5 items.

```php
array [

  page1 => items [
    0 => items 1
    1 => items 2
    2 => items 3
    3 => items 4
    4 => items 5
  ]

  page2 => items [
    0 => items 1
    1 => items 2
    2 => items 3
  ]

]
```

I need the key value to continuously increase like this:

```php
array [

  page1 => items [
    1 => items 1
    2 => items 2
    3 => items 3
    4 => items 4
    5 => items 5
  ]

  page2 => items [
    6 => items 1
    7 => items 2
    8 => items 3
  ]

]
```

I have no idea how to do that. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please update the question with the code you are using for creating the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with `$sl` variable:

```
$newArray = array();
$sl = 1;
foreach($array as $arrayValue){
  foreach($arrayValue as $value){
    $newArray[$sl] = $value;
    $sl++;
  }
}
```

Here we create a new array and put every data on this and increase the key number with `$sl++;`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer effectively merges the two arrays, so you lose the original multidimensional structure; you no longer have `page1`, `page2` etc. This may not be a problem at all for you, which is fine. If you wanted to keep the original structure you can use:

```
$index = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == array_key_first($array)) {
        $lastKeyValue = (array_key_last($value) + 1);
        continue;
    } else {
        $countElements = count($value);
        $saveArray = $value;
        $value = array_slice($value, $countElements);
        for($i = 0; $i < $countElements; $i++) {
            $value[$lastKeyValue] = $saveArray[$i];
            $lastKeyValue++;
            $array[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```